# Array of numbers, check to see which 2 numbers the current value is between

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of numbers. 0,136,1084,3521,3961,5631,6510,7901,8204 (which are the current scrollTops of all of the sections on one page.) I'm trying to find a way to take the current window scrollTop and find out which of these values it's currently between so that when the page is being scrolled, the active navigation item switches.

Currently, while scrolling, 'current page' skips 0 and goes straight to 1 in the array, and as a result, is unable to catch the last page.

```
currentPage = 0;
divOffset = new Array();

function setCurrentPage() {
    divOffset = []; //this ends up as 0,136,1084,3521,3961,5631,6510,7901,8204

    //get offset and ID of each section and add to array.
    $(".section").each(function() {
        sectionOffset = $(this).offset();
        divOffset.push(Math.round(sectionOffset.top));
    }); 

    bodyOffset = $(window).scrollTop(); 

    for(i=0; i < divOffset.length; i++) {
        if( divOffset[i] >= bodyOffset ) {
            currentPage = i;
            $('#mainNav li').removeClass("active");
            $("#mainNav li #a-" + currentPage).parent().addClass("active");
            return false;
        }
    }   

}
```

My navigation looks something like this:

```
<ul id="mainNav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#a-0" class="navA" id="a-0">home</a></li>
    <li class="menuLI"><a>works</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#a-1' class='navA' id='a-1'>Websites</a></li>
            <li><a href='#a-2' class='navA' id='a-2'>Illustrations</a></li>
            <li><a href='#a-3' class='navA' id='a-3'>Photomanipulations</a></li>
            <li><a href='#a-4' class='navA' id='a-4'>Glam Guitars</a></li>
            <li><a href='#a-5' class='navA' id='a-5'>Logos</a></li>
            <li><a href='#a-6' class='navA' id='a-6'>Photography</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#a-7" class="navA" id="a-7">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a-8" class="navA" id="a-8">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can look at it here: http://glowtagdesign.com/index2.php#a-0

Comment: have you tried removing the first element (0) from the array? that should work!

Comment: I did, and it worked... sortof. It still skipped the last value in the array though.

Comment: Why do you think it skips the first index? Try logging the values of bodyOffset and divOffset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the array is sorted, try this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length && pos < arr[i]; i++)
{
}
// i is now the number of items in the array less than pos
// pos is less than the first item -> 0
// pos is greater than the last item -> arr.length
```

Comment: Since that's a body-less for loop, the iterator is outside of the loop, and the number of iterations is undeterminable beforehand, I think a while loop would be the better choice here: ``var i = 0; while(i < arr.length && pos < arr[i]) { i++ }``

Comment: @David: They mean the same. What's the difference?

Comment: I know they mean the same; I'm simply saying that the *intent* is clouded when written as a ``for`` loop: the ``for`` loop was constructed for situations where you simply want to iterate through some determinable number of loops and perform some operation each time. A ``while`` loop has no concept of an iteration variable, it just re-executes until the conditional statement is false, which is what you're doing. I may be acting like a grandpa, here, but ``for`` and ``while`` have different *semantics*, and your solution fits the ``while`` mold better. (Due to the lack of body when this way.)

Comment: @David: I see what you mean. I'm one of those people who uses `for` loops any way I can, but again, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: for some reason, everytime I've tried the while loop, it freezes my page.

Comment: @z0mbieParade: Did you remember the `i++`?

Comment: @KendallFrey, this is why we have different constructs, though. Would you like to look at the JS code of someone *way* too infatuated with functional programming who solved this problem like this? ``arr.reduce(function(prev, val) { return pos < val ? val : prev; });`` (Actually not as bad as I originally expected.)

Comment: @KendallFrey, well, at least I know the ``reduce`` mechanism would be the slower one, here: extra stack operations to call the anonymous function, and the loop doesn't short-circuit when the correct value is found. (You'd need to wrap that thing in ``arr.indexOf(arr.reduce....`` now that I think about it)

Comment: This seems a bit hacky to me, but if I strip the first 0 off the array and then add an extra value to the end (999999999), it works fine. I feel like there should be a better way though.

Comment: @z0mbieParade: You don't need a very large value at the end of the array. It will handle that fine. And I don't know if jQuery offers a 'non-hackish' way, but 2 (effective) lines seems pretty simple to me.